Package updates via TeX Live Utility after MacTeX via homebrew on Apple Silicon Mac
I recently got a new Apple Silicon Mac, and migrated my system from my old Intel Mac. On my old Intel Mac, MacTeX was installed at /usr/local/texlive/ folder. Now, using brew install --cask mactex on my new Mac, it installed at /Library/TeX/ folder.
So, first I uninstalled the old homebrew system as well as all the subfolders in /usr/local. Then, I ran the new TeX Live Utility app (GUI version), which is located at /Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/ folder. When I ran this and updated the packages, somehow, it recreated /usr/local/texlive folder and put all these update packages there. Also it duplicated /usr/local/texlive/bin/ whose contents are the same as /Library/TeX/texbin. I felt something is wrong. What should I do to correctly update the packages in /Library/TeX? Thanks a lot for your help!

Have you tried downloading and installing MacTeX directly from https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html?

I’m voting to close this question because there actually isn’t an issue

After all, /Library/TeX/texbin and /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/universal-darwin are the same folder (the former is a symbolic link pointing to the latter). So, I don’t have to worry about it!
